# Payout and get paid from companies through an invoice

Tags: income

For a project I am working on we have some companies sell their products through the system I made. They can sell items online and people can order them online but they have the option to pay for it online or in the store with cash. They will have to pay a small percent commission fee over their revenue. If they have a lot of cash payments but no online payments they have to pay me, if they have only online payments they will get paid by me. Now I have a question regarding invoices to the companies.

What kind of invoice do I have to send to the company if the company has more online payments so they have to get money? And what kind of invoice do I have to send if they have received more cash payments so they have to pay me?

Does someone maybe have an example of these invoices for me?

Comment: So, when someone orders online but pays in-store, how is that transaction tracked?  Does the customer come in with a code or something else to identify their purchase?  How is the store notified of the sale for pickup by the customer?  Your system should include a mechanism for tracking this so that you know when an order placed online has been picked up in-store, which would tell you all you need to know about what is due to you and what you need to pay out.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you issue an "invoice" to a party that needs to pays you. If you are the one paying, then either you would be given an invoice by the other party, or if you are the one that knows how much to pay (and not them), you could either tell them how much to invoice you, or just pay them and issue them a "statement" along with your payment.

Since in your case you have the possibility of 2-way payments, you can do all the math and just issue "statements" along with all of your payments to your customer. (I assume this is the most likely scenario.) If the in-store sales are ever so much higher that your customer owes you money, just issue an invoice along with the statement when necessary.

As for example invoices or statements, just search for [invoice template](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=invoice%20template) online.